# Difference between "парень" and "любовник"?

Tags: разница

What is the difference between these two words ?

Comment: what's your thought on this issue so far? what makes you think that they are equivalent?

Comment: @shabunc , a russian girl asked me if I want her as my girl. So I looked at english dictionary to find out a word for "lover" in english, like a partner, or darling. The dictionary showed me the word: Любовник , and I asked her "Любовник?" and she said "парнем". I didn't think those two were different at that time. But 2 days later, she told me, it is a pity that I only want to be любовником with her. I was confused. To answer your question, the dictionary caused this confusing for me. I thought word "lover" has exact same meaning in russian, but it seems not.

Comment: a-ha, now I see her point )

Comment: "К жене пришел молодой любовн**и**к когда муж пошел за пив**о**м"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One thing surprisingly not mentioned so far (and one most important one) is that `парень` is way narrower, it's **not** like boyfriend in modern English - in non-ironical way it's applicable only for younger people. A student can introduce her boyfriend: "Это мой парень", someone in late thirties will sound actually more comical.

`Любовник` is not a boyfriend either. One will sound unintentionally funny if they introduce their boyfriend/girlfriend as `любовник`/`любовница`. The word is used to describe a relationship that is often kept in secret. It also implies that either one or both of the participants are married. `любовник`/`любовница` relationships are unofficial in a wide sense of the term "unofficial".

The fact that both terms are not fully equivalent to boyfriend is the reason why in colloquial slang word `бойфренд` gains more and more traction.

Comment: I would say that in recent decade or two the usage of "парень" (and "девушка") much widened. It's no longer comical at all to refer to a man in late 30s as "парень", although from a 18-19 years old girl that would not be met with much approval.

Comment: @Alexander I can agree that it upper limit is increasing, but still it used way more buy younger people.

Answer (score 9):

Парень is a boyfriend. Любовник is a lover. Любовник usually implies an illicit affair, where one or both participants are married.

Answer (score 6):

***Парень*** (a cognate to Lithuanian ***berniukas***) makes an emphasis on the relationship while ***любовник*** makes emphasis on love-making:

***У неё есть парень / нет парня. А парень-то у тебя, подруга, есть?*** - the phrases are usually within a scale of socially acceptible / polite talks.

Therefore, it's ok to ask a girl you hardly know or don't know at all;

***У тебя есть парень?***

And it's not ok to ask her

***У тебя есть любовник?***