# How do you say "Boyfriend" and "My boyfriend" in Russian?

Tags: перевод, лексикон

How do you say "Boyfriend" and "My boyfriend" in Russian?

Comment: related - https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/15478/difference-between-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-and-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba/15479#15479

Answer (score 6):

«Мой молодой человек» or «мой парень». The last version is mostly common, especially in everyday speech.

Comment: please tend to leave answers that are not already provided.

Comment: @shabunc This is a full answer and was not yet provided. Please consider deleting your comment which is out of place.

Comment: @wondering please clarify - both "молодой человек" and "парень" were mentioned in other answers.

Comment: @shabunc None of the other answers can be accepted as one because neither contains both «Мой молодой человек» and «мой парень». And that's a problem because both are frequently used and it's hard to tell which one more - it depends on particular social environment. Thus, this answer, containing both expressions, is to my mind the only candidate for an answer that can be accepted. What do you think?

Comment: @wondering I think that this way will encourage people to just combine existing answers without adding any additional value apart from the very fact of compilation. This answer was not deleted, was not converted to comment - I've just indicated the fact that answers supposed to add something new. That said - I believe it's totally fine to keep both the answer and the comment.

Comment: Sure, I got your point, it should be more than a compilation. I agree on this.

Answer (score 2):

Girls usually like phrase "Молодой человек" which means "Young man"

Answer (score 1):

"**Boyfriend**" Mostly it will says:

> Парень

like young boy or a man in american meaning.
And "My boyfriend" will end up with just adding a `my` at the beginning:

> Мой парень

Comment: A note: "Парень" (A guy) needs a context, like "Мой парень/Ее парень". Without context, the meaning would be confusing, just like "a guy"'s meaning in English.

Answer (score 0):

Часто так и говорят: бойфренд, мой бойфренд.

Comment: I'm a native Russian speaker (Moscow), and I've never heard *anyone* saying *“бойфренд”* unironically.  It's almost always *“парень”.*

Comment: Тоже никогда не слышал.

Comment: Корпус русского языка находит кучу вхождений. Практически столько же, сколько "мой парень".

Comment: Это зависит от местности и от круга общения. "Бойфренд" вполне в ходу, но вероятно, не в ваших кругах.

Answer (score 0):

Друг, дружок, кавалер, любовник, молодой человек, парень - here can be many some connotations...

друг (officially, or not so sexual)

дружок (more ironically, or.. no..; intimate f.e.)

кавалер ( archaic.. ironically,...or no :>)

любовник (more sexual and intimate)

любимый (less sexual than last, but intim. too)

возлюбленный (many pathos, intimate)

хахаль (Ukrainianism, slightly disdainfully ..)

молодой человек (officially,like words from a parents for this case)

милёнок (very country-style, intimate)

ухажёр (ironically, simple style)

партнер (very cold, pragmatic :>)

cекс-партнер (cold too, but w. sex. connotation) :>

парень (usually)

f.e... :> it's depend on :>